# SoapUI "failed to load url" error when loading WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl, soapui

I keep having some weird problems. The main one is that I keep getting the following error when trying to add a WSDL to a new project:

```
Error loading [https://.../token?wsdl]: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url; https://.../token?wsdl, 0 -
```

Here's the message recorded in the error.log file:

```
java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url; https://.../token?wsdl, 0 - 
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.UrlWsdlLoader.load(UrlWsdlLoader.java:184)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlLoader.loadXmlObject(WsdlLoader.java:121)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getDefinitionParts(SchemaUtils.java:535)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getDefinitionParts(SchemaUtils.java:524)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionCache.update(AbstractDefinitionCache.java:97)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext$Loader.construct(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:226)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorkerDelegator.construct(SwingWorkerDelegator.java:46)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:149)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I verified that the application at that URL is up and running, and I can get to the WSDL from a web browser, but I keep getting this error message no matter what. I am using SoapUI 4.5.0 (32-bit) on a Windows 7 box. I've also tried the 64-bit version with the same results. It happens whether I am on VPN or not.

Do you know why I might be getting this error?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have had similar problems and worked around them by saving the WSDL locally.  Don't forget to save any XSD files as well.  You may need to edit the WSDL to specify an appropriate location for XSDs.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried to load the WSDL directly before but I had completely forgotten about the XSD. It works now!

Comment: Hi chrismead, Even I am doing the same.

Comment: Not so nice workaround. Disabling proxy (see next answer) helped a lot better.

Comment: I am new for these please let me know where to add xsd file

Answer (score 80):

I have had the same problem. I resolved it by disabling the proxy in the SoapUI preferences.
(source : http://www.eviware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=12460)

Comment: Same problem for me on 4.5.1 Win 32. The proxy was enabled and set to port 8081. Disabling the proxy in `Files->Preferences->Proxy Settings` allowed it all to work.

Comment: You can also quickly disable / enable the proxy via the proxy icon on the tool bar (a server with a red or green dot)

Comment: Ubuntu on 5.2.1 `File -> Preferences -> Proxy Settings` set to `None`.

Comment: That was the exact problem. :)

Comment: The link is borken and changing proxy to None didn't help. do you have different steps of fixing this issue?

Comment: Thank you! I supposed it did not work due to https, so i tried to import the certificate before. Bad choice! Your solution worked for me!

Answer (score 43):

In my case the server were the service was installed was configured only for TLS. SSL was not allowed. So you have to update SoapUI vmoptions file by adding the server TLS version

```
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

You can find vmoptions file under SoapUI installation folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\bin\soapUI-5.0.0.vmoptions
```

Comment: This solved the problem in my case. Additionally I had to enable client authentication in the soapUI preferences as the web server requires it.

Comment: This worked like a charm for my situation. Thank you!

It is frustrating SoapUI doesn't make this more of an obvious option/error message.

Comment: macOS users will have to modify soapui.sh in `/Applications/SoapUI-5.3.0.app/Contents/java/app/bin/soapui.sh` (and other .sh scripts in the same directory)

Add: `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2"`

Above: `$JAVA $JAVA_OPTS -cp $SOAPUI_CLASSPATH com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI "$@"`

Comment: Don't change your server to allow SSL. Maintain some dignity.

Comment: Don't know why is this answer not in the top!?

Comment: This worked for me for SoapUI version 5.3.0. I got this error [link] (https://i.imgur.com/R8L2Kxm.jpg). Added (-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2) to the vmoptions file. Only thing had to close SoapUI and restart again.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when trying to load a WebService implemented in MS Dynamics AX. Because I was connecting via VPN to my network, something went wrong with IPv6 settings. After Googling, I found the solution here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852

Answer (score 1):

In my case the

```
 Error loading [https://.../token?wsdl]: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url; https://.../token?wsdl, 0
```

was caused by fake certificate.
If you get the following in browser

```
"There is a problem with this website’s security certificate."
```

this is the case.

The resolution was to import a certificate to

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

Which is default java used by SOAPUI

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem with IPV6 address SOAP UI picking. Adding the following JVM option fixed it for me:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

I added it here:

```
C:\Program Files\SmartBear\soapUI-4.5.2\bin\soapUI-4.5.2.vmoptions
```

Comment: nice one. But why ipv6 adress has this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the wsdl file look for the import element, which looks like this :

```
`<import  namespace="nameSpaceValue" location="Users/myname/.../targetxsdName.xsd"/>`
```

Change the location attribute in the above element to the location of your xsd files stored locally, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution helped me:

```
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

In SoapUI-5.3.0.vmoptions.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to an erroneous schemaLocation in the WSDL file.

Indicate the correct location (either path on the disk or xsd url)  of the xsd file in the wsdl file

exp

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://xyz:8080/" schemaLocation="http://172.17.16.53:9080/auth/authorizationBS?xsd=1"></xsd:import>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your Web Application with the default port of 8080, please try to change the port to some other value and run your application again and trigger again your SOAPUI request. As you might have history projects in your SOAP UI workspace with port number 8080, might create issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to use a SOCKS proxy. It appears that SoapUI does not support SOCKS proxys. I am using the Boomerang Chrome app instead.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to modify the **java.security** file:

```
\SoapUI-5.3.0\jre\lib\security\java.security
```

Comment code syntax:

```
#jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048
#jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and in my case, the problem was that I was using "localhost" in the URL.
I resolved that changing the localhost word for the respective IP, `(Windows + R -> cmd -> ipconfig)` then read the IP and write it to the URL replacing the "localhost" word

Answer (score 0):

Close and reopen soapui. Probably is a bug of the application

Answer (score 0):

For java version above 1.8,
Use below command to setup soapUI jar

```
java -jar --add-modules java.xml.bind --add-modules java.xml.ws <path for jar file+jar file name.jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update SoapUI version to SoapUI 5.5.0.  This error causes when I tried to load wsdl, because of old SoapUI version