# Error in SOAP-UI while loading the wsdl hosted in localhost

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I am getting the following error while loading a localhost wsdl. If I try other wsdls which are not hosted locally it works fine. Please help.

```
Error loading [http://localhost:7001/xyz?wsdl]: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url; http://localhost:7001/xyz?wsdl, 0
```

Errors from the log

```
ERROR:com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.InvalidDefinitionException
   com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.InvalidDefinitionException
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlLoader.makeInvalidDefinitionException(WsdlLoader.java:119)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlLoader.loadXmlObject(WsdlLoader.java:112)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getDefinitionParts(SchemaUtils.java:488)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getDefinitionParts(SchemaUtils.java:477)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionCache.update(AbstractDefinitionCache.java:94)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext$Loader.construct(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:209)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorkerDelegator.construct(SwingWorkerDelegator.java:46)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:131)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have gone through this link and it did not solve the problem.
[soapUI failed to load url error when loading wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088483/soapui-failed-to-load-url-error-when-loading-wsdl)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the errors you're getting, here is a list of possible solutions that come to mind:

- Check the URL of the WSDL in a browser. Does it open? If not, your server is not started and the WSDL contract is unreachable.
- Make sure you are not using a proxy and you don't have some proxy option set in the SOAP UI preferences
- There might be a problem with the validity of your WSDL, but it is impossible to tell without inspecting it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I fire the wsdl in a browser it works. But in soap it throws error.

Comment: I mean not open wsdl, but access it at localhost address

Answer (score 0):

In may case the problem was I was trying to load the .xsd instead the .wsdl

-as both are very similar when open in browser.. is easy to make the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Added the following parameters to the .vmoptions file, and restarted SoapU helped resolve this for me.

```
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```